# Get Parameter passed from query string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm calling this url by passing query string parameter, i have to pass name parameter to details.py

> Url is :

```
http://www.somesite.com/details.py?name=test
```

i tried using `request` but i can't get this parameter.

> Code:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

`requests` is for performing http calls

To "get" the value from that string, you'd want `urllib.parse` module for parsing URIs

Getting a query parameter on the server-side would depend on what web framework you're using

Comment: Thanks i'm not using any framework, i'm using python 3.6, how i will get current url and pass it to urlparse eg. `parsed_url = urlparse(url)`

Comment: I don't know what context your code runs in. Are you implementing a server? Or are you just a client? Or are you doing data analysis on a collection of urls? What do you mean "get the url"? As far as you've shown, you already have that as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `urllib` to parse urls;

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

url = 'http://www.somesite.com/details.py?name=test'

# parse the url 
parsed_url = urlparse(url)

# parse the request's parameters
parsed_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)

# get the 'name' parameter 
name = parsed_params['name'][0]

print(name)
```

```
>>> 'test'
```